# Solve the reccurence $T(n) = 3T(\sqrt[3]{n}) + \log_{2}(\log_{2}n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> $T(1) = 1 $ ,
>
> $T(n) = 3T(\sqrt[3]{n}) + \log_{2}(\log_{2}n)$.

I tried to define $ n = 2^{k}$.

So, $T(2^k) = 3T(2^{\frac{k}{3}}) + \log_{2}k$

Then defin $S(k) = T(2^k)$

So ,$S(k) = 3S(\frac{k}{3}) + \log_{2}k$

And now im pretty stuck,
Someone has an idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: If is it true , than use master-theorem

Comment: Can you help me plz ?

Comment: read about master theorem in wiki

Comment: I know what is it, but still dont know know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have solved $S(k) = 3S(\frac{k}{3}) + \log_{2}k$

Now, you can use [master theorem case $(1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form) :

> $T(n)=a\;T\!\left({\frac {n}{b}}\right)+f(n) \space\text{where}\space
> > {\displaystyle a\geq 1{\mbox{, }}b>1} $
>
> If ${\displaystyle f(n)=O\left(n^{c}\right)} $ where ${\displaystyle
> > c<\log _{b}a} $ (using big O notation)
>
> then:
>
> ${\displaystyle T(n)=\Theta \left(n^{\log _{b}a}\right)} $

You have $a=3$, $b=3$, and $f(k)=\log_2{k}$

Therefore,

$f(k)=O(k^{\log_3{3}})$

$\implies \log_2{k}=O(k)$

Hence, 
$S(k)=\Theta(k)$

Putting back $n=2^k$, we get

$T(n)=\Theta(\log_2{n})$